# I made a donut but after rendering it came out very weird

Tags: rendering, modifiers

[image: This is the donut that I made]

[image: And this is what it came out after rendering]

Kindly help me out here, this is my first time using blender
[image]

Comment: hell please share your file https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Added the file.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of your *Shrinkwrap* modifier, it's still enabled for render, either disable it for render or decrease its *Offset* which is very high compared to the object size (or bring back the *Offset* to 0):

[image]